# We can now reduce the maximum number of simultaneous questions in the HNQ. Should we?

Tags: discussion

Stack Exchange recently changed how the Hot Network Questions list works. In a [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325060/updating-the-hot-network-questions-list-now-with-a-bit-more-network-and-a-litt) they mention that each site can limit their exposure to only allow a certain number of questions from a site on the list if the site decides to do that in a meta-question.

> **Each site can only have a max of five questions on the HNQ list at any given time.**
>
> This is a big, much-requested change and we may reduce the number in the future even further. We're starting it higher than some might want (suggestions went as low as one per site) because sites that have had a lot of exposure through the HNQ may see a dramatic drop in visits, so we need to be careful to find the right number here and possibly do some testing at different levels.
>
> *This number is also configurable on a per-site basis*, so if a site wants to reduce their HNQ footprint, we can lower it even more, even to zero if a site wishes to be excluded entirely. *Sites will need to go through a meta discussion before requesting this change* and it will be up to the site itself to request a change rather than having the limit imposed upon it (unless we lower the maximum for the entire network). So for example, Stack Overflow can't vote to kick Movies & TV off the list entirely because they don't want to see spoilers for the last season of Game of Thrones, but Movies & TV can ask that fewer of their questions be shown so that they can devote sufficient time to those that are.

Here is the necessary meta question: Do we want to limit the number to something less than five?

Answer (score 9):

#### No.

Electrical Engineering does not seem to suffer from a large number of questions in the Hot Network Questions. When it happens, there is only one or at most two at the same time.

Together with the new time limit on HNQ entries and the possibility of a diamond-moderator to remove a specific trivial or bad question, I don't think we should reduce it to zero either.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betteridge%27s_law_of_headlines

Comment: This is what's there currently: [Potentiometer like component](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/427028/potentiometer-like-component). Basically "what is this electronic thingie". How it got so many up-votes I have no idea. Maybe because it is in HNQ?

Comment: @Lundin Yep, I don't think I've ever seen a HNQ question from here that's non-trivial, the question is how the end up there in the first place.

Comment: @Lundin Because it's intriguing and/or potentially easy to answer. All "what is this electronic thingie" questions end up in the HNQ. EE veterans click on it because they think "Well, people can't ask such simple things, can they? Let me check...". And newbies click because they think "Cool, I can probably answer that". At that point, it doesn't get a lot of votes yet, but a lot of views. After some time, the views count is high enough to make it to HNQ, and then it gets votes from people not familiar with EE who were happy to learn something. But in the end, it isn't that harmful, is it?

Answer (score 3):

No.  If it ain't broke, don't fix it.  I don't see a problem to solve here

Answer (score -1):

No. Why would you want to limit site exposure?

Comment: Because you get an inrush of users to a single question who can't downvote and don't know anything about what's a good or a bad question, so trivial and sloppy questions end up having 20 or 30 upvotes, and basically every answer on that question as well, including answers that would normally be downvoted.

Comment: We get that no matter what we do, I don't think the HNQ really changes the amount of new users. It changes the upvotes, I wouldn't say thats a bad thing

Comment: I think the point here is: we wouldn't mind exposure but it has to be good questions. Not "I pried my phone open, ooh look at all these weird chip things! What's this thingie here for?" because that draws the wrong kind of attention. We should have questions that attract electrical engineer types (or at least EE students) and not DIY types.

Comment: Or just take a page out of Olin's playbook and chase off all the DIY types, except now we have to 'be nicer'